# SQL Server Group records and count totals with similar names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count the total number of open diary records for each user.
My problem is the user names have three different prefixes.  CC  YY or none.
I can replace the prefixes making the names identical but I'm having trouble grouping them by this modified name.  The data is spread across three tables and I need to exclude closed and inactive records.

This simplified query returns an example of the un-grouped results I want.

```
select sname 
 ,( Select count(lDiaryHeaderID)
    FROM DiaryHeader
    inner join OwnersCorporation on lObjectID = lOwnersCorporationID
    where 
    sObjectType = 'B' 
    AND DiaryHeader.bRecordClosed = 'N'
    AND DiaryHeader.dActionDueDate < cast (GETDATE() as DATE)
    AND OwnersCorporation.bManaged  = 'Y'
    AND tbluser.lUserID = strata.dbo.OwnersCorporation.lUserID 
  ) as TotalOverDue

FROM tblUser 
WHERE bActive = 'Y'
AND bManager = 'Y'
ORDER by sName
```

Result

```
sname               TotalOverDue
Belinda Smith       525
CC Belinda Smith    18
CC Julie Brown      13
CC Kris White       0
CC Sharon Towell    38
Colleen Black       131
Jessica Jones       166
Joanne Beigh        284
Julie Brown         449
YS Belinda Smith    31
YS Colleen Black    0
YS Joanne Beigh     21
```

What I want to do is remove the CC and the YS prefix from the name
and group them as a single entry and add the totals together.

Desired Result

```
sname               TotalOverDue
Belinda Smith       574
Julie Brown         462
Kris White          0
Sharon Towell       38
Colleen Black       131
Jessica Jones       166
Joanne Beigh        305
```

I came up with this.

```
select Replace(Replace(sName, 'CC ',''), 'YS ','')    
 ,( Select count(lDiaryHeaderID)    
    FROM DiaryHeader    
    inner join OwnersCorporation on lObjectID = lOwnersCorporationID    
    where     
    sObjectType = 'B'    
    AND DiaryHeader.bRecordClosed = 'N'    
    AND DiaryHeader.dActionDueDate < cast (GETDATE() as DATE)    
    AND OwnersCorporation.bManaged  = 'Y'    
    AND tbluser.lUserID = strata.dbo.OwnersCorporation.lUserID     
  ) as TotalOverDue    

FROM tblUser     
WHERE bActive = 'Y'    
AND bManager = 'Y'    
group by sName
```

However I get this error message

Column 'tblUser.lUserID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I put lUserID in the group by clause it just shows the duplicated the usernames as expected.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong and how I should be doig this.
Thanks
David

**UPDATE:**

My actual solution has multiple columns and I removed two of them to simplify my question.  Now that I'm trying to expand it again I have run into more problems.

Here is my attempt to add the other two columns back in. DueToday and TotalDue however my totals are snowballing.

Update 2
Thanks to Phylyp's eagle eye.  He spotted some cut and paste errors and this code now returns the desired result.
Thanks to everyone who responded with some very interesting and diverse solutions.  I'll stick with the first one that works :)

```
    select Replace(Replace(sName, 'CC ', ''), 'YS ', ''),
    coalesce(sum(od.cnt), 0) as TotalOverDue,
    coalesce(sum(dt.cnt), 0) as DueToday,
    coalesce(sum(td.cnt), 0) as TotalDue

from tblUser u

left join (
    select oc.lUserID,
    count(lDiaryHeaderID) cnt
    from DiaryHeader dh
    inner join OwnersCorporation oc on lObjectID = lOwnersCorporationID
    where sObjectType = 'B'
        and dh.bRecordClosed = 'N'
        and dh.dActionDueDate < cast(GETDATE() as date)
        and oc.bManaged = 'Y'
    group by oc.lUserID
    ) od on u.lUserID = od.lUserID

left join (
    select oc.lUserID,
    count(lDiaryHeaderID) cnt
    from DiaryHeader dh
    inner join OwnersCorporation oc on lObjectID = lOwnersCorporationID
    where sObjectType = 'B'
        and dh.bRecordClosed = 'N'
        and dh.dActionDueDate = cast(GETDATE() as date)
        and oc.bManaged = 'Y'
    group by oc.lUserID
    ) dt on u.lUserID = dt.lUserID

left join (
    select oc.lUserID,
    count(lDiaryHeaderID) cnt
    from DiaryHeader dh
    inner join OwnersCorporation oc on lObjectID = lOwnersCorporationID
    where sObjectType = 'B'
        and dh.bRecordClosed = 'N'
        --and dh.dActionDueDate < cast(GETDATE() as date)
        and oc.bManaged = 'Y'
    group by oc.lUserID
    ) td on u.lUserID = td.lUserID

where bActive = 'Y'
and bManager = 'Y'
group by Replace(Replace(sName, 'CC ', ''), 'YS ', '')
```

Comment: That is closer the names are now grouped correctly  if I comment out the line in the sub query "AND tbluser.lUserID = strata.dbo.OwnersCorporation.lUserID" but of course the totals are all wrong.  With that line uncommented I still get the error

Comment: `) od on u.lUserID = od.lUserID` is correct. `) dt on u.lUserID = od.lUserID` should be changed to `) dt on u.lUserID = dt.lUserID`. Likewise `) td on u.lUserID = od.lUserID` should be changed to `) td on u.lUserID = td.lUserID`

Comment: When you're left-joining the nested query, you've given an alias like "od", "dt", "td". However, the join statement that follows it, where you join on `u.lUserID = XY.lUserID` always has XY as "od", it should reflect the alias for the relevant nested query.

Comment: It looks like I received three correct answers which is fabulous.  It looks like I can only mark one answer as correct and I implemented @GurV answer so his got the tick.  Thanks again to everyone.

Comment: To the downvoter: Why the -1.  I tried very hard to make my question clear.  I researched the problem provided data, desired results and I had a go at solving the problem myself.  Then posted the solution I used and thanked the people who helped.  What does a guy have to do?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, and I too can't see a reason for the downvote, yours is easily among the better questions here. However, your comment did make me come back to see your updates, and I have an observation to offer.

Comment: I do have to point out that while it is your decision, I'm not comfortable with performing `REPLACE(sName, 'YS ', '')`. If you have a person named `GLADYS JONES`, it will be converted to `GLADJONES`. Granted that you might get away with such a problem if the name is entered in title case (i.e. Gladys Jones), but it still feels quite close. I would point you to my answer which uses `sName LIKE ('CC%')` to check for a name that starts with CC or YS. I'd recommend you use that `CASE ... END` statement instead of the `REPLACE` function.

Comment: @Phylyp, i appreciate the effort you put in  to your answer.  The requirement for the duplicated user names will soon be gone.  The fact they are still there at all is because of a work around by my boss that is harder to fix that it is to tell me to merge them in the report :)  With only a dozen or so users in the list the chances of getting a username like that is slim.  To my surprise there are 184 baby names ending in ys and that is just the boy names.  I might just have to make that change after all :) http://www.babynamespedia.com/end/m/ys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to group by the replace expression instead of the column sName. Also, be careful with the replace as it replaces the match anywhere in the string.

Second, replace the correlated subquery with a left join.

```
select Replace(Replace(sName, 'CC ', ''), 'YS ', ''),
    coalesce(sum(od.cnt), 0) as TotalOverDue
from tblUser u
left join (
    select oc.lUserID,
        count(ldhID) cnt
    from DiaryHeader dh
    inner join OwnersCorporation oc on lObjectID = locID
    where sObjectType = 'B'
        and dh.bRecordClosed = 'N'
        and dh.dActionDueDate < cast(GETDATE() as date)
        and oc.bManaged = 'Y'
    group by oc.lUserID
    ) od on u.lUserID = od.lUserID
where bActive = 'Y'
    and bManager = 'Y'
group by Replace(Replace(sName, 'CC ', ''), 'YS ', '')
```

Comment: I'm just trying to get my head around the abrrivations you have added.
What are ldhID and locID, they both come up as invalid column names

Comment: :) Silly me lDiaryHeaderID and lOwnersCorporatinID  Why should you type them again.
By the way I did think about "CC " and "YS " but they will be unique amoung my user names.

Comment: @David - It should be fine in that case.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer it works but I wish I could learn how to reach that result.  If I don't learn anything I will be destined to make the same mistake again.
Also the Users with zero records came up as Null.  I know the process down the track that has to deal with data probably won't like NULL.  How can I return zero ?

Comment: Don't worry I figured out the zero thing
(Select Isnull (sum(od.cnt),0)) as TotalOverDue

Comment: @David - I too updated the answer with `coalesce(sum(od.cnt), 0)`. `Coalesce` is SQL standard and lots of databases support it. `ISNULL` is SQL server only.

Comment: I did see Coalesce in my google search.  I'll swap to that instead.
While expanding the solution from my cut down example back to the original problem I have two more columns very similar to the one shown (TotalOverDue). DueToday and TotalDue.  This is a simple change to the condition but i'm getting confused how the joins should now work.  I'll expand my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my recommendation below.

I'm using a `CASE` expression to check if the name **starts with** CC or YS, and if so, remove the first 3 letters. This ensures that any CC/YS present within the name itself (e.g. as initials) aren't inadvertently removed, as is the case with the `REPLACE()` function.

```
SELECT 
    tblUserNameNormalized.sNameNormalized 
  , COALESCE(SUM(od.cnt), 0) AS TotalOverDue 
  , COALESCE(SUM(dt.cnt), 0) AS DueToday 
  , COALESCE(SUM(td.cnt), 0) AS TotalDue 
FROM 
  ( 
      SELECT 
          lUserID
        , CASE 
          -- Check if the name starts with CC or YS, and skip the first 3 letters in that case 
          WHEN sName LIKE ('CC%') THEN SUBSTRING(sName, 4, LEN(sName) - 3) 
          WHEN sName LIKE ('YS%') THEN SUBSTRING(sName, 4, LEN(sName) - 3) 
          -- Else use the name as-is 
          ELSE sName 
          END AS sNameNormalized 
      FROM 
        tblUser 
      WHERE bActive = 'Y'
        AND bManager = 'Y'
  ) as tblUserNameNormalized 
  LEFT JOIN ( 
    select oc.lUserID,
    count(lDiaryHeaderID) cnt
    from DiaryHeader dh
    inner join OwnersCorporation oc on lObjectID = lOwnersCorporationID
    where sObjectType = 'B'
        and dh.bRecordClosed = 'N'
        and dh.dActionDueDate < cast(GETDATE() as date)
        and oc.bManaged = 'Y'
    group by oc.lUserID
  ) od on tblUserNameNormalized.lUserID = od.lUserID
  LEFT JOIN (
    select oc.lUserID,
    count(lDiaryHeaderID) cnt
    from DiaryHeader dh
    inner join OwnersCorporation oc on lObjectID = lOwnersCorporationID
    where sObjectType = 'B'
        and dh.bRecordClosed = 'N'
        and dh.dActionDueDate = cast(GETDATE() as date)
        and oc.bManaged = 'Y'
    group by oc.lUserID
    ) dt on tblUserNameNormalized.lUserID = dt.lUserID
  LEFT JOIN (
    select oc.lUserID,
    count(lDiaryHeaderID) cnt
    from DiaryHeader dh
    inner join OwnersCorporation oc on lObjectID = lOwnersCorporationID
    where sObjectType = 'B'
        and dh.bRecordClosed = 'N'
        --and dh.dActionDueDate < cast(GETDATE() as date)
        and oc.bManaged = 'Y'
    group by oc.lUserID
    ) td on tblUserNameNormalized.lUserID = td.lUserID 
GROUP BY tblUserNameNormalized.sNameNormalized
```

Comment: Thanks Phylyp.This works too but I'm still stuck on how to include my other two columns back in.  Although it left out the zero records

Comment: @DavidPollard - Good point on the zero records, I should have used an `OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` to join `tblUser`. i.e. `RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblUser`.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't make a difference.

    Right Outer JOIN tblUser ON tbluser.lUserID = OwnersCorporation.lUserID

Comment: @DavidPollard - Please see my comments beneath your question, for the other two columns.

Comment: @DavidPollard - I've updated my query based on the revised query you've given (including the 2 columns).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will give the error because in your code you are using GROUP BY clause with out aggregate function.

Please try the script below.

Select a.sName,Sum(TotalOverDue) As TotalOverDue
FROM (
        select Replace(Replace(sName, 'CC ',''), 'YS ','')   As sName 
         ,( Select count(lDiaryHeaderID)
            FROM DiaryHeader
            inner join OwnersCorporation on lObjectID = lOwnersCorporationID
            where
            sObjectType = 'B'
            AND DiaryHeader.bRecordClosed = 'N'
            AND DiaryHeader.dActionDueDate < cast (GETDATE() as DATE)
            AND OwnersCorporation.bManaged  = 'Y'
            AND tbluser.lUserID = strata.dbo.OwnersCorporation.lUserID
          ) as TotalOverDue

```
    FROM tblUser     
    WHERE bActive = 'Y'    
    AND bManager = 'Y'  ) a
```

Group By sName

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar, This also answered the question exactly but as I mentioned I simplified my problem down to a single column and now I can't see how to add the other two back in again.  I need to include a count of records DueToday and TotalDue.  Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi David, As per your problem i was not able to assume how your tables are design. Could you please share the table structure with its data so that i can run your script and modify it to your desired result.

Comment: Hi Sudhakar, As I said your answer matched the question so your solution is good.  I received three working solutions but can only mark one as the answer. which is the one I used, not that it was a better answer that yours just faster.   The actual tables are complex and I can't make the data public, without coming up with a pile of test data.  As it is I changed the names to protect the innocent :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replace like this then group what ever you want:

```
declare @CC varchar(20)
declare @YS varchar(20)
Set @CC = 'CC sample name'
Set @YS = 'CC sample name'
select replace(@CC,'CC ',''),replace(@YS,'YS ','');
```